# JSON to Pandas: is there a more elegant solution?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have some JSON, returned from an API call, that looks something like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "code": "OK",
        "msg": ""
    },
    "report_name": "FAMOUS_DICTATORS",
    "columns": [
        "rank",
        "name",
        "deaths"
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "row": [
                1,
                "Mao Zedong",
                63000000
            ]
        },
        {
            "row": [
                2,
                "Jozef Stalin",
                23000000
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to convert the JSON into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
rank    name            deaths
1       Mao Zedong      63000000
2       Jozef Stalin    23000000
```

I wrote this and it works, but looks a bit ugly:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

columns = eval(r.content)['columns']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = eval(r.content)['columns'])

for row in eval(r.content)['data']:
    df.loc[len(df)+1] = row['row']
```

Is there a more elegant/Pythonic way to do this (e.g. possibly using pandas.io.json.read_json)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read_json` function of `pandas` is a very tricky method to use. If you don't know with certainty the validity of your JSON object or whether its initial structure is sane enough to build a dataframe around, it's much better to stick to tried and tested methods to break your data down to something that `pandas` can use without issues 100%.

In your case, I suggest breaking down your data to a list of lists. Out of all that JSON, the only part you really need is in the `data` and `column` keys.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib

js = json.loads(urllib.urlopen("test.json").read())
data = js["data"]
rows = [row["row"] for row in data] # Transform the 'row' keys to list of lists.
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=js["columns"])
print df
```

This gives me the desired result:

```
   rank          name    deaths
0     1    Mao Zedong  63000000
1     2  Jozef Stalin  23000000
```

Answer (score 0):

see pandas.io.json.read_json(path_or_buf=None, orient=None, typ='frame', dtype=True, convert_axes=True, convert_dates=True, keep_default_dates=True, numpy=False, precise_float=False, date_unit=None

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html

Comment: That doesn't really help with anything. OP is already aware of this function. Unless you can provide OP with an example of *how* to use it, this is better off as a comment.